# How to convert A[B[C]] to B[A[C]] if A and B are monads?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'm looking for a more general solution which exploits monads (and monoids possibly) to achieve the same as 
`if( xs.contains(None) ) None else Some(xs.flatten)` does for `xs` of type `Seq[Option[A]]`.

How can I do that with Scalaz? I feel like I'm missing something evident.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having two monads is both not enough (for `M`) and more than enough (for `N`)—which adds up to not enough, of course—but if `M` has a `Traverse` instance and `N` has an `Applicative` instance, you can use `sequence`. For example:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def foo[A](xs: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = xs.sequence
```

This has the semantics you want. Note that I'm using `List` instead of `Seq`, since Scalaz 7 no longer provides the necessary `Traverse` instance for `Seq` (although you could easily write your own).

---

As you've noticed, the following won't compile:

```
List(Some(1), Some(45)).sequence
```

Although it's fine if you throw a `None` in there:

```
scala> List(Some(1), None, Some(45)).sequence
res0: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

This is because the inferred type of `List(Some(1), Some(45))` will be `List[Some[Int]]`, and we don't have an `Applicative` instance for `Some`.

Scalaz provides a handy `some` method that works like `Some.apply` but gives you something that's already typed as an `Option`, so you can write the following:

```
scala> List(some(1), some(45)).sequence
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 45))
```

No extra typing necessary.

Comment: In REPL with Scalaz 7 it fails because it can't find a Traverse typeclass instance for Seq. Maybe there's something else I should import?

Comment: You can use `List` instead of `Seq`, or provide your own instance for `Seq`—I'm not sure why the `Seq` instances have disappeared in 7.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! But I'm frustrated with its behaviour: besides the `Seq` issue there's another one requiring you to specify the type explicitly: `val xs = List(Some(1), Some(45)); (xs : List[Option[Int]]).sequence`