# how to generate string combinations from a list of strings?

Tags: scala

Beginner question. Given a list of **arbitrary length** that contains one or more characters in a string such as List("ab", "def", "t"), how do you generate a list containing all the combinations? Ex. List("adt", "aet", "aft", "bdt", ...) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, you are looking for the Cartesian Product of a `Seq[Seq[T]]`, right?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive method could look like this:

```
def foo(xs: List[String], current: String = ""): List[String] = xs match {
  case head :: Nil =>
    head map { c =>
      current + c
    } toList

  case head :: tail =>
    head flatMap { c =>
      foo(tail, current+c)
    } toList

  case _ => Nil
}
```

Beware that this method is NOT tail recursive, so it will overflow for long lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
List("ab", "def", "t").foldLeft(List("")){ (acc, s) =>
  for(prefix <- acc; c <- s) yield (prefix + c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an operation called `sequence` that more generally turns a `F[G[A]]` into a `G[F[A]]` (you need to know certain things about `F` and `G`—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519) or [this blog post](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2011/01/iteration-in-scala-effectful-yet.html) for more detail).

With [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/), for example, you can write this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

List("ab", "def", "t").map(_.toList).sequence.map(_.mkString)
```

Or equivalently:

```
List("ab", "def", "t").traverse(_.toList).map(_.mkString)
```

And you'll get the following, as expected:

```
List(adt, aet, aft, bdt, bet, bft)
```

This isn't much more concise than the standard-library version with `foldLeft`, but `sequence` is a useful abstraction to know about.

Comment: When `F` and `G` are both `List`, I find it hard to intuit what `sequence` will do. I guess now that I have read your answer and pondered it, I will remember it.

Answer (score -1):

Just starting with Scala myself but you can use 'subsets' method to do most of the work for you:

```
val lst = List("ab", "def", "t")
val re = (for(l <- lst) yield (l.toCharArray)).flatten.toSet.subsets.toList
val res = for(r <- re) yield (r.mkString)
```

which gives you:

```
res: List[String] = List("", e, t, f, a, b, d, et, ef, ea, eb, ed, tf, ta, tb, t
  d, fa, fb, fd, ab, ad, bd, etf, eta, etb, etd, efa, efb, efd, eab, ead, ebd, t
  fa, tfb, tfd, tab, tad, tbd, fab, fad, fbd, abd, etfa, etfb, etfd, etab, etad,
   etbd, efab, efad, efbd, eabd, tfab, tfad, tfbd, tabd, fabd, etfab, etfad, etf
  bd, etabd, efabd, tfabd, etfabd)
```

Comment: If you downvote, you can at least comment why you do that, as I have written 'I'm starting with scala...' and was expecting that this answer won't be the gr8est, at least maybe I'll learn smth if you leave the comment