# Processing a list of Scalaz6 Validation

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz

Is there an idiomatic  way to handle a collection of Validation in Scalaz6?

```
val results:Seq[Validation[A,B]]
val exceptions = results.collect{case Failure(exception)=>exception}
exceptions.foreach{logger.error("Error when starting up ccxy gottware",_)}
val success = results.collect{case Success(data)=>data}
success.foreach {data => data.push}
if (exceptions.isEmpty)
   containers.foreach( _.start())
```

I could think of using a fold when looping on results, but what about the final test?

Answer (score 9):

The usual way to work with a list of validations is to use `sequence` to turn the list into a `Validation[A, List[B]]`, which will be be empty (i.e., a `Failure`) if there were any errors along the way.

Sequencing a `Validation` accumulates errors (as opposed to `Either`, which fails immediately) in the semigroup of the left-hand type. This is why you often see `ValidationNEL` (where the `NEL` stands for `NonEmptyList`) used instead of simply `Validation`. So for example if you have this result type:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type ExceptionsOr[A] = ValidationNEL[Exception, A]
```

And some results:

```
val results: Seq[ExceptionsOr[Int]] = Seq(
  "13".parseInt.liftFailNel, "42".parseInt.liftFailNel
)
```

Sequencing will give you the following:

```
scala> results.sequence
res0: ExceptionsOr[Seq[Int]] = Success(List(13, 42))
```

If we had some errors like this, on the other hand:

```
val results: Seq[ExceptionsOr[Int]] = Seq(
  "13".parseInt.liftFailNel, "a".parseInt.liftFailNel, "b".parseInt.liftFailNel
)
```

We'd end up with a `Failure` (note that I've reformatted the output to make it legible here):

```
scala> results.sequence
res1: ExceptionsOr[Seq[Int]] = Failure(
  NonEmptyList(
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a",
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b"
  )
)
```

So in your case you'd write something like this:

```
val results: Seq[ValidationNEL[A, B]]

results.sequence match {
  case Success(xs) => xs.foreach(_.push); containers.foreach(_.start())
  case Failure(exceptions) => exceptions.foreach(
    logger.error("Error when starting up ccxy gottware", _)
  )
}
```

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519) for more detail about `sequence` and about `Validation` more generally.

Comment: What about the complimentary case? I wanna succeed if at least a Validation has succeeded ?

Comment: That sounds like you may be working against the grain of `Validation`. In 7 you could reduce the list with `|||`, but in 6 you'd need something like the sum using the semigroup for the right projection of `Either` (or you could write your own `|||`).

Comment: Can you point me towards some resources who explain what a Semigroup is?