# Set sequencing type puzzle

Tags: scala, types, scalaz, scalaz7

Last night in responding to [this question](https://twitter.com/ryanonsrc/status/340270466226851840), I noticed the following:

```
scala> val foo: Option[Set[Int]] = Some(Set(1, 2, 3))
foo: Option[Set[Int]] = Some(Set(1, 2, 3))

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> foo.sequenceU
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

That is, if `foo` is an optional set of integers, sequencing it returns a set of integers.

This isn't what I expected at first, since sequencing a `F[G[A]]` should return a `G[F[A]]` (assuming that `F` is traversable and `G` [is an applicative functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519)). In this case, though, the `Option` layer just disappears.

I know this probably has something to do with some interaction between one of the supertypes of `Set` and the `Unapply` machinery that makes `sequenceU` work, and when I can find a few minutes I'm planning to work through the types and write up a description of what's going on.

It seems like a potentially interesting little puzzle, though, and I thought I'd post it here in case someone can beat me to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wow, yeah. Here's what I can surmise is happening.  since Set doesn't have an Applicative of its own, we are getting the Monoid#applicative instance instead:

```
scala> implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, Set[Int]]].TC
res0: scalaz.Applicative[_1.M] forSome { val _1: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative,Set[Int]] } = scalaz.Monoid$$anon$1@7f5d0856
```

Since Monoid is defined for types of kind * and applicative is defined for types of kind * -> *, the definition of Applicative in Monoid sorta wedges in an ignored type parameter using a type lambda:

```
final def applicative: Applicative[({type λ[α]=F})#λ] = new Applicative[({type λ[α]=F})#λ] with SemigroupApply...
```

Notice there that the type parameter `α` of `λ` is thrown away, so when Applicative#point is called, which becomes Monoid#zero, instead of it being a Monoid[Set[Option[Int]]] it is a Monoid[Set[Int]].

larsh points out that this has the interesting side-effect of alllowing sequenceU to be (ab)used as sum:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).sequenceU
res3: Int = 6
```