# Scalaz: transforming State of Option into Option of State

Tags: scala, scalaz

Trying to wrap my mind around Scalaz State monad and monad transformers.

What I want to do is to implement something like:

```
def transform[S,A](o: State[Option[S], A]) :Option[State[S,A]]
```

Is this even possible ? How would I do it ?

Comment: Can you replace `Option` with `Monad` and then `State` with `Monad`? Then you have `M1[M2[X]]` and just want `M2[M1[X]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this operation should do. Here's an applicable state value: `State((s: Option[String]) => (s, 0))`. What do we get when we transform it?

Comment: Note that in general you can use `sequence` to turn `M[N[A]]` into `N[M[A]]` if [`M` has a `Traverse` instance and `N` has an applicative functor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519). That won't work here, however, since there's no `Traverse` for `State[_, A]`.

Comment: The reason I wanted to have this function is because I had a State transformer that worked on S but not on Option[S]. I can always write another transform that will work on Option. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do. Thus, the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a legitimate implementation that you will not like

```
def transform[S,A](o: State[Option[S], A]: Option[State{S,A]] = None
```

If you try for another implementation, the question is when can transform return a Some? 
`State[Option[S], A]` is `Option[S] => (Option[S], A)`. And you are trying to get a `S => (S,A)`. 
Given `s: S`,  you must return an `(S,A)` pair. Passing s to the original state is ok, you just wrap it in `Some`. But you get an `(Option[S], A)` which  may lack an `S`. No way to transform that to an (S,A). Except if you accept that the state will sometime fail.

There is no way you can know in advance that `o` will never return a None state (even if you further constraint to not returning a None state when given a Some state), so there is no way you can make an useful decision as to whether transform should return `Some` or `None`. You can either return `None` all the time, or `Some` all the time, and have `State` application sometime fail. Whichever one you choose, the result type is useless. If `None`, the transform function itself is useless, if `Some`, typing the result as an `Option` brings you nothing.