# Scalaz flipping nested existential / validation mono-whatevers-nads around pre-applicative-building

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz, applicative

I've got the following :

```
gt.map(_.singleVal) |@| lt.map(_.singleVal)
```

They are of type `Option(Validation(T))` but they should be `Validation(Option(T))`

It is ok for something to not exist, but it is not ok for something that exists to be invalid. In other words I would want `None` to be interpreted as `Success(None)`

It struck me as a very common thing to want to do. Is there any sugar in scalaz that does this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by `Validation(T)` you mean something like `ValidationNel[Throwable, T]`, since `Validation[T]` isn't anything and `Validation[E, T]` doesn't have an applicative functor instance unless `E` has a semigroup instance.

What you're looking for is probably `traverse` (or `traverseU` if you want to avoid writing out the type parameters). You can write the following, for example:

```
scala> case class Foo(singleVal: ValidationNel[Throwable, String])
defined class Foo

scala> val x = some(Foo("hey".success))
x: Option[Foo] = Some(Foo(Success(hey)))

scala> val y = none[Foo]
y: Option[Foo] = None

scala> println(x.traverseU(_.singleVal))
Success(Some(hey))

scala> println(y.traverseU(_.singleVal))
Success(None)
```

In general if `M` has a `Traverse` instance and `N` has an applicative functor instance, you can transform a `M[A]` into a `N[M[B]]` given a function `A => N[B]` with `traverse` (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519) for some additional discussion).

Comment: Hey Travis, thanks for looking past my impreciseness, and the detailed answer :D