# Does the "natural" function from Seq[Option[T]] to Option[Seq[T]] have a name?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

Does this function (or perhaps some monadic generalisation of it) have an established name?

```
def foo[T](in: Seq[Option[T]]): Option[Seq[T]] = {
    val res = in.flatten.seq
    if (res.length == in.length) Some(res) else None
}
```

Is there a more elegant implementation?

Comment: It's usually called "sequence" (have a look at Future.sequence for instance)
https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sequence

Read this for info about the scalaz implementation: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day12

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, the function from `Seq[M[A]]` to `M[Seq[A]]` (where `M` is a monad) is usually referred to as `sequence`.

The Haskell definition of it is:

> Evaluate each action in the sequence from left to right, and collect the results.

There's no generic implementation of it in the scala standard library, but you can see an example for the `Future` type here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L487-L491

You can find generic implementations of `sequence` in libraries such as [`cats`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/5ae45578c3558694aadd8ce2e4a92c7453139a6b/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala) or [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/06fae66b1e0a0df7942c9fe114f5593511b7548a/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala).

One thing to notice, is that `sequence` is a specific case of a more generic operation, usually called `traverse`.

Haskell defines `traverse` as

> Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these actions from left to right, and ignore the results.

Now, given the definition, `sequence` can be implemented in terms of `traverse`, simply by using the identity function (`x => x`) as the map operation of `traverse`.

If you take a look at the implementations mentioned above, you'll find that they all leverage this generalization and they all use `traverse` to implement `sequence`.